# Instantiation of derived template class objects

Tags: c++, crtp

I have class template acting as base class for derived classes. The idea was to take advantage of "static polymorphic" through the CRTP trick.

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
class BASE
{
  public:
    void write() {static_cast<T*>(this)->write(); }
};

class DER1 : public BASE<DER1>
{
  public:
    void write(){
       std::cout << "Calling write() inside DER1 " << number << std::endl;}   
  private:
    int number = 11;
};
```

I tried 2 different ways of instantiating  derived class object, and, I found that one of the two ways is not correct. But I could not understand why.

```
int main(void) {

    BASE<DER1> der1_objA ;
    der1_objA.write();

    DER1 der1_objB ;
    der1_objB.write();
    return 0;
}
```

In fact, I get as output

```
Calling write() inside DER1 1880535040    [ random number]
Calling write() inside DER1 11            [correct number ]
```

Can anybody explain me where the issue is?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The static cast is only defined if you are actually a base subobject...

Comment: in the `BASE<DER1>` instance there is no `DER1` instance, but only a `BASE` that tries to cast itself to something that it isnt

Comment: In the end it's slicing.

Comment: @tobi303 The area for answers is down here!! :-) ... I cannot find a better wording than yours.

Comment: @skyjack me neither :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define an object of type BASE, it is *just* a BASE, but inside it you case the this pointer to something it is not (DER1), and proceed to use it through that invalid pointer.  That is undefined behavior, and garbage is a normal consequence.  The only time when CRTP works is when the dynamic type of the object actually is the template parameter passed to the base class.  That is, if BASE thinks it really is a DER1, it really must be a DER1.  Casting itself to DER1 when it is only BASE and using that pointer for DER1 operations is undefined behavior, not much different from doing this:

```
int x = 42;
std::string * sptr = (std::string*)&x; // extremely questionable
sptr->clear(); // undefined behavior
```

You should consider making the BASE constructors have "protected" access level, to prevent the simple cases of misuse.  This way the base constructor can only be called by derived objects, so you can't accidentally instantiate the base in isolation:

```
template <typename T>
class BASE
{
  protected:
    BASE() = default;
    BASE(BASE const&) = default;

  public:
    void write() {static_cast<T*>(this)->write(); }
};
```

Then instead of getting garbage, you get:

```
BASE<DER1> objA ;
objA.write();

error: 'BASE<T>::BASE() [with T = DER1]' is protected within this context
BASE<DER1> base;
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `BASE<DER1>` instance there is no `DER1` instance, but only a `BASE` that tries to cast itself to something that it isnt.

PS: [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLiDezv_Frk)  about the c++ memory model is quite related, but goes beyond what I could explain in simple words.